# Inter thread control handling in Blackberry (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, blackberry

I have the following scenario.

```
void foo(){
\\do some work
\\invoke a thread to do some heavy work
\\do some work after the thread finishes.
}
```

I could split this up in this way.

```
void foo1()
{
//pre thread work
//start thread
}

void thread(){
//do heavy work
//invoke foo2() to run from main thread
}

void foo2(){
//do post thread work
}
```

The question is how do I invoke `foo2()` (to run in main thread) from the other thread?
In Android we have the `Handler` class for this. How could this be done in Blackberry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoke foo2 using `UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater()` from your spawned thread.

Documentation here:
[UiApplication](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiApplication.html)